# spring batch : itemprocessor is not getting all the data read by reader

Tags: spring-batch

I am reading from MongoDB using custom Iteamreader bean. My reader is returning data as per pageSize(50) defined in reader. But processor is getting only first 31 rows of data from 50. I tried various chunk sizes but some how processor is getting only first 31 rows.

Please help me in find the bug...I tried listeners but not able to find issue..

---- config XML ----

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.xxx.yyy.batch.kernel" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.xxx.yyy.batch.dao" />

    <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- Enable Annotation based Declarative Transaction Management -->
    <tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true"
        transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <!-- Creating TransactionManager Bean, since JDBC we are creating of type 
        DataSourceTransactionManager -->
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <batch:job id="txnLogJob" job-repository="jobRepository"
        restartable="true">
        <batch:step id="txnload">
            <tasklet allow-start-if-complete="true">
                <chunk reader="txnLogItemReader" writer="txnLogItemWriter"
                    processor="txnLogProcessor" commit-interval="20" />             
            </tasklet>
        </batch:step>

        <batch:listeners>
            <batch:listener ref="completionListener" />
        </batch:listeners>
    </batch:job>

    <bean id="completionListener"
        class="com.xxx.yyy.batch.listeners.JobCompletionNotificationListener" />


    <bean id="jobParametersDAOImpl" class="com.xxx.yyy.batch.dao.JobParametersDAOImpl" />

    <bean id="batchLoader" class="com.xxx.yyy.batch.kernel.BatchLoader" />

    <bean id="batchjobParameter" class="com.xxx.yyy.batch.dao.Batch_Job_Parameters" />



    <bean id="txnLogItemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter"
        scope="step">
        <property name="shouldDeleteIfExists" value="true" />
        <property name="resource" value="file:target/test-outputs/output.txt" />
        <property name="lineAggregator">
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.PassThroughLineAggregator" />
        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="txnLogProcessor"
        class="com.xxx.yyy.batch.processor.MessageContextItemProcessor" />

    <bean id="jobLauncher"
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
        <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jobRepository"
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean">
        <property name="databaseType" value="MYSQL" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    </bean> 

    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.xxx.yyy.common.DataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
        <property name="connectionProperties" value="${jdbc.connectionProperties}" />
        <property name="initialSize" value="${jdbc.initialSize}" />
        <property name="maxTotal" value="${jdbc.maxTotal}" />
        <property name="maxIdle" value="${jdbc.maxIdle}" />
        <property name="minIdle" value="${jdbc.minIdle}" />
        <property name="maxWaitMillis" value="${jdbc.maxWaitMillis}" />
        <property name="testOnBorrow" value="${jdbc.testOnBorrow}" />
        <property name="testWhileIdle" value="${jdbc.testWhileIdle}" />
        <property name="testOnReturn" value="${jdbc.testOnReturn}" />
        <property name="validationQuery" value="${jdbc.validationQuery}" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

---

custom reader bean:

```
@Bean
    public MongoItemReader<MessageContext> txnLogItemReader() {
        MongoItemReader<MessageContext> reader = new MongoItemReader<MessageContext>();
        reader.setPageSize(50);
        reader.setCollection("txnlog");
        reader.setTemplate(mongoTemplate);

        String query = null ;
        query = "{ \"audit_info.created_on\": { $gt: { \"$date\" : ?0  }, $lte: { \"$date\" : ?1  } }, "
                        + "$and: [ { \"processing_status\": { $in: [?2] } } ] }" ;




        reader.setQuery(query);        

        //Timestamp to_date_timestamp = jobParametersDAOImpl.getCurrentTimeStamp() ;        

        Batch_Job_Parameters job_param = jobParametersDAOImpl.getBatchJobParameters() ;
        String from_date = job_param.getFrom_date().toString() ;
        String [] splitstr = from_date.split(" ") ;
        from_date = splitstr[0]+"T"+splitstr[1]+"00Z" ;

        String to_date = job_param.getTo_date().toString() ;
        splitstr = to_date.split(" ") ;
        to_date = splitstr[0]+"T"+splitstr[1]+"00Z" ;

        List<Object> parameterValues = new ArrayList<Object>() ;
        parameterValues.add(from_date) ;
        parameterValues.add(to_date) ;       
        parameterValues.add(job_param.getTxnlog_status_list()) ;       

        reader.setParameterValues(parameterValues);

        reader.setTargetType(com....MessageContext.class);
        Map<String,Direction> sorts = new HashMap<String,Direction>() ;
        sorts.put("audit_info.created_on", org.springframework.data.domain.Sort.Direction.ASC) ;
        reader.setSort(sorts);

        return reader;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updated answer since the question shifted focus**

I would have the `MessageContextReadConverter` not return `null` and instead do validation in the `Processor`. If the `Processor` returns `null`, it just increments the filter count as opposed to confusing the `Step` into thinking there are no more rows to process.

Comment: MongoDB contains more than 500 rows,I can see all the 50 rows being read.I put listeners (step,chunk,read) in the configuration. 
Output of listener is:
"before step"
"before chunk"
"before read"
50 rows of data
"after read"
19 times:
"before read"
"after read"
20 rows of data processed by processor and writer
"after chunk"
"before chunk"
10 times:
"before read"
"after read"
"before read"
10 rows of data processed by processor and writer
"after chunk"
"after step"

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented MessageContextReadConverter implements Converter and I am returning null in case conversion is not done. So, in case of null, read() method is not passing elements further to Processor/Writer. Issue is  Converter doesnt allows exception to be thrown. Looking how to resolve this part.